# Exit second command based on exit of first command in parallelly executed commands

Tags: bash, usage-statistics, simultaneous-calls

I want to run a command which is resource intesive and use another command to dump hardware stats while first command is running. I ofcourse want to stop the second one when first exits.

E.g.

```
ping 8.8.8.8 & dstat -T -f temp.csv
```

Obviously ping is not intensive but you get the picture.

With the above command the first exits but second part keeps on running. I want dstat to stop when ping ends. Also, important that this happens in one liner command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `dstat` in the background, and save its PID in a variable. Then run `ping` in the foreground, and kill `dstat` when it finishes.

```
dstat -T -f temp.csv &
dstat_pid=$!
long_running_command
kill $dstat_pid
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It confirms that I was not in the wrong direction. However, I can't get it to work in one line, probably because of & in the first line.

Comment: Why does it have to be one line?

Comment: OK I got it. dstat _t -f temp.csv & dstat_pid=$! ; ping 8.8.8.8 -c 4 ; kill $dstat_pid runs but the temp.csv has no data.

Comment: Yes, in general you can replace newline with `;` to turn multi-line commands into one-line.

Comment: What finally works is 'dstat -T -f -o temp.csv & dstat_pid=$! ; ping 8.8.8.8 -c 4 ; kill $dstat_pid'

Comment: I thought `ping` was just an example. Obviously it has to be a command that terminates by itself.